# How to concatenate two class arrays to an allocated space in c++

Tags: c++

I have two class arrays, each one with a pointer pointed to. I just wonder is that possible to concatenate these two arrays to a new allocated space. What is in my mind is std::copy(). Is that possible to use copy()? Or any other idea?

Comment: You could just iterate over the two arrays...

Comment: Some reason you're not using standard containers? Masochism, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array and iteratively copy each old array into the new array using for loops

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `std::copy` is the appropriate tool.

```
char array1[6] = "haha ";
char array2[4] = "you";
char array3[10];

std::copy(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1), std::begin(array3));
std::copy(std::begin(array2), std::end(array2), std::begin(array3)+5);
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704c9f6e4b5df460))

However, the `char` arrays are *not* the appropriate tool, as you can see from all the hardcoded numbers and horrid pointer arithmetic.

Use standard containers, instead.